# Flutter, how can I center a widget in a row, but not the other?

Tags: flutter, layout

For this screen:

[image]

I would like to make the date in black be in center like the code in orange, and the refresh button follows the date, which may be a little bit on the right.  Secondly, how can I reduce the height of space in between orange code and the date, and in between the date and the search item.

Here is part of my code:

```
Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
            child: Text(
              adminPassword(_today),
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.orange[800]),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children:[
              Center(
                child: Text(DateFormat('d/M/y').format(_today).toString()),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _today = DateTime.now();
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
           ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 10, 12, 20),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Search Item'),
              controller: _searchItemController,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 45,
            width: 250,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.teal, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {}
              child: Text(
                'Search',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put another `IconButton` with `0` opacity to get this:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Opacity(
      opacity: 0,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
    Text('asdasdasdasd'),
    IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ],
),
```

also your second issue, space between the two rows is because of icon button size in second row, change it to this:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 24,
  width: 24,
  child: IconButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: @TonyLam was it what you want?

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: you put another icon button on the other side of row but put it invisible. in that way the row thinks there is other icon button there but the ui does n't show that.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly.  But how can I reduce the space between the code and the row?

Comment: I updated my answer for second issue. @TonyLam

Answer (score 0):

Just put some left padding in date text,

```
Padding(
  padding:EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
  child:Text(DateFormat('d/M/y').format(DateTime.now()).toString()),
),
```